# JS Регулярное выражение - проверка URL

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Задача следующая - нужно составить регулярное выражение, которое проверит URL, и если оно имеет формат `https://vk.com/[0-9A-z._]` , но НЕ `https://vk.com/album[0-9]` выдать нужный результат.

```
var value = document.getElementById('name').value;
var regex = /^https:\/\/vk.com\/^album\d(\d\w){1,100}+$/;
 if( regex.test(value) )
    alert('ok');
else
    alert('fail');
```

не работает.
подскажите, что делаю не правильно?

Comment: то есть нужно выделить, не является ли ссылка - ссылкой на альбом ВКонтакте.

Comment: Может, [`/^https:\/\/vk\.com\/(?!album-?\d)[^\/]*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/SgxxP8/3)? Или [`^https:\/\/vk\.com\/(?!album-?\d)[^\/\s]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/SgxxP8/4/)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо! Первый вариант точно рабочий!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
/^https:\/\/vk\.com\/(?!album-?\d)[^\/]*$/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/SgxxP8/3)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `https:\/\/vk\.com\/` - подстрока `https://vk.com/`
- `(?!album-?\d)` - сразу после текущей позиции в строке не должно быть подстрок типа `album-1` или `album1`
- `[^\/]*` - 0 и более любых символов, отличных от `/`
- `$` - конец строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^https:\/\/vk\.com\/(?!album-?\d+$)[\w.]+$/
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Работает, если после album идет тире, если тире нет - все равно проходит проверку..

Comment: @СергейБелов, где? https://i.stack.imgur.com/z68Dd.png

Comment: https://parser2.ru/test.html

Comment: @СергейБелов, и? Всё же работает.

Comment: альбомы ВК могут иметь ссылки вида https://vk.com/album123_456 или https://vk.com/album-123_456 (с тире и без), первый вариант возвращает ok, второй fail ..

Comment: @СергейБелов, написал свой ответ, можешь посмотреть.